# How do I add a collection of builtin book actions to my app's section?

Tags: collections, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

My app publishes the builtin actions:

- og.likes
- books.reads
- books.wants_to_read

I can create a collection for my app's section that includes the builtin og.likes (Called recently liked) but I can't figure out how to add the other collections to my section. (books.reads, books.wants_to_read)

When I goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/opengraph/collections and click "Create a New Collection" the Action Type dropdown only includes Like. Read and Want to Read are missing. All these actions have been approved for my app.

What am I missing here?
How do I add these collections to my app's section?

Thanks,
Blair

Answer (score 0):

1. you've to create the action for your app (read and wants_to_read), they are default actions
2. you've to create the message and add the action to the message
3. you've to add the message to your collection

It's kinda confusing, that on facebook 'actions' are the 3rd option under collection and message. But I guess you figured out already :)